# Raspberry Pi GPIO

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm a newbie here, but I love Mathematica very much and would like to assist our kids in Raspi class to use it. 75 kids of age from 8 to 15. We did various kind of "blinky" trials on Raspi, with Scratch, rpi.gpio, WiringPi, or SunVox, and so on.

Now I've noticed the GPIO commands in Mathematica.

Actually I've already made it work but I have questions in the reference.
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/device/GPIO.html

Q1: Why is the limitations for the available pins?

"On a Raspberry Pi, the following pins are available for reading and writing: 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 22, 23, 24, 25, 28, 29, 30, 31."

Q2: What are the pins of 28, 29, 30, 31?? We only have GPIO 2 - GPIO 27 at the header of the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I found it!

Because it was made for Raspberry Pi 1 which has the 26-pin header instead of 40.
GPIO 0,1,5,6,12,13,16,19,20,21,26 are missing there. And "P5 header" has GPIO 28, 29, 30, 31.

http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/09/raspberry-pi-p5-header/